# Hide elements in list view for non active records in Filemaker

Tags: filemaker

I've got a list view of a number of records. I would want to hide certain layout elements on the records which isn't the active one. Is this possible?

It should be possible with the "Hide object when"-functionality, but I'm not sure what the calculation should be.

I'm using Filemaker 13.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Script Trigger to set a global variable (e.g., $$ID) with that record's Primary Key (ID) when a record is loaded, then hide the button/layout object if `not $$ID = PKID`.

Adapted from the technique at http://forums.filemaker.com/posts/e591b47fdc.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a statistic field in your table that counts the current number of any field that is filled in every record. An ID or timestamp would be the best guess. Then hide your portal object(s) in the inspector with "YourFieldName" <> Get(ActiveRecordNumber). Should be done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/20490661)

Comment: Could you please explain why not? In my Filemaker database it works.